# Fairly New to Python - Global Varibable Issue

Tags: python, python-3.x

was wondering if I someone could lend a hand with the issue I am having with my python 3.4 code. I have found it hard to word my problem and searching the web for an answer has been difficult, so I thought it would be easier if I were to show the code and the issue to be resolved.

```
cola_cost = 2
surcharge = 0

def calc_takeaway(cost):
    global surcharge
    cost = cost * 1.05
    surcharge = surcharge + (cost * 0.05)

cola_place = input("Do you want your cola to go? ")
if cola_place == "yes":
    calc_takeaway(cola_cost)

print("$"cola_cost) ## cola cost should be $2.10 but instead prints out $2
print("$"surcharge)
```

Basically, my `cola_cost` will not change its global value after being passed into the `calc_takeaway` function. Sorry if this is too basic I would kist like to get this issue solved. Thank you.

EDIT: I'd also like to mention that I would like to use the function on different cost variables (i.e fanta_cost, water_cost...) as well.

Comment: You are not changing the global variable `cola_cost`. You are changing the function parameter `cost`, which acts as a local variable in the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider avoiding `global` in the first place if possible atleast when alternate methods are possible, because [they are a bad usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19158339/why-are-global-variables-evil). Instead of `global`, use simple parameter passing and function return concepts to handle the issue.

```
cola_cost = 2
surcharge = 0

def calc_takeaway(cost, surcharge):
    cost = cost * 1.05
    surcharge = surcharge + (cost * 0.05)
    return cost, surcharge

cola_place = input("Do you want your cola to go? ")
if cola_place == "yes":
    cola_cost, surcharge = calc_takeaway(cola_cost, surcharge)

print("$", cola_cost) # $ 2.10 
print("$", surcharge)
```

Comment: Very much appreciated Austin and thank you for the tip! Enjoy your day.

Answer (score 0):

Your global variable is sent by value, and so you're not really changing it,
but rather a copy of it. Here is a simpler example based on your code:

```
cola_cost = 2

def try_to_change_global_variable(cost):
    cost = 174

try_to_change_global_variable(cola_cost)

print(cola_cost)
```

And when you run it you'll get:

```
$ python cola.py
2
```